# ASP.Net Passing array from Controller to View to javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have ASP.Net MVC3 application. And My task is to read points from file and display them. For reading points from file I use DLL. I draw them in javascript. 
Here is my code:

```
// Controller
{
  IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary("lib.dll");

  // getting points from DLL. I get then as array of strings to serialise later
  string[] points = new string[0];
  GetArrayPointsAsStrings(points); // I get coordinates - [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ..]

  FreeLibrary(lib);

  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
  string serialized_points = serializer.Serialize(points);

  return View(new MyModel(serialized_points));
}

// Model
public class MyModel
{
  public string Points { get; private set; }
}

// View
@{
var m = Model;
var array_of_strings_points = m.Points;
}

// object from javascript
var js_obj = new js_obj();
var points_string = '@Html.Raw(@array_of_strings_points)';
js_obj.DrawPoints(points_string);

//js
//.. and here in DrawPoints() I parse the string of points and draw point
```

My question is: Is it ok to pass all serialized points to string from controller to javascript this way? May be there is better way to pass all points to javascript?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: Is it ok to pass all serialized points to string from
>   controller to javascript this way? May be there is better way to pass
>   all points to javascript?

On your model keep the real CLR type (`string[]`). You don't need to be JSON serializing in your controller:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string[] Points { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller populate and pass the view model to the view:

```
string[] points = ...
MyModel model = new MyModel();
mode.Points = points;
return View(model);
```

and finally in your view:

```
@model MyModel
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_obj = new js_obj();
    var points = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Points));
    js_obj.DrawPoints(points);
</script>
```

Now if your `js_obj.DrawPoints` expects a JSON string as parameter instead of a javascript array of 
strings you could pass it like this:

```
@model MyModel
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_obj = new js_obj();
    var points = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Points));
    js_obj.DrawPoints(JSON.stringify(points));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But @Html.Raw expects string.. I cannot pass array of strings there. That was the reason why I used serializer

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my answer and forgot to `Json.Encode` the model property before passing it to the `Html.Raw` helper. I have updated my answer with a working example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. And I have last question: how can I parse array in DrawPoints() after I used JSON.stringify(points)? 
     var data_parsed = JSON.parse(i_points);
     data_parsed[1]; or data_parsed.pop() does not work..

Comment: You don't need to be doing a `JSON.stringify` when calling the `DrawPoints` method. In this case you don't need to be `JSON.parse` in the method. The argument will directly represent a javascript array object that you could manipulate directly.